# Call uv_async_send from std::thread doesn't work

Tags: c++, node.js, libuv, node.js-addon

I have a problem with calling `uv_async_send` from `std::thread`. Here the code snippet

In c++ addon for node-js initialization thread:

```
...
uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), async_v8_cb_, OnAsyncResponse);
...
```

In `std::thread` (started from initialization thread)

```
...
uv_async_send(async_v8_cb_);
...
```

I expect that `OnAsyncResponse` will be called from node-js main thread. But nothing happens. So, is it possible to call `uv_async_send` from any thread(`std::thread` in my case)? And what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The documentation states that should work. What is your main loop doing at the moment you call `uv_async_send` ?

Comment: Brilliant! After `uv_async_send` I made some blocking call. It's the reason. Thank you very much!